# Tictactoe setting up play board error

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, tic-tac-toe

Here's my code of the displayBoard function using pointers:

```
void tictactoe::displayBoard(){
    board = new char* [SIZE];
    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r ++){
        board[r] = new char[SIZE];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < COL_WIDTH - 1; i++)
        cout << SPACE;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << setw(COL_WIDTH) << i;
    cout << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++){
        cout << setw(COL_WIDTH) << r;
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
            //cout << SPACE << board[r][c] << SPACE  <<  VERTICAL; 
            cout << SPACE << board[r][c] <<  VERTICAL;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            cout << SPACE;
        for (int d = 0; d < SIZE * COL_WIDTH; d++)
            cout << DASH;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Somehow it doesn't display correctly. but when I run it without using pointers, it display correctly.

And also when I run it, I enters the row, and col to place my piece, no matter what I enter, it couldn't accept it. Io I am wondering the problem is coming from my displayBoard function.

Comment: A. What do you mean *without using pointers*? B. Unless you have a very good reason, you should be using `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`instead of `char**`

Comment: All those arrays you've allocated contain random garbage; you haven't initialized them to any particular values. Then you print that random garbage.

Comment: `when I run it, i enters the row, and col to place my piece` No part of the code you've shown accepts any input from the user. The last paragraph of your question appears to be asking about code you have not in fact shown.

Comment: Add [`std::fill(board[r], board[r]+SIZE, ' ');`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) after each row is allocated. That will probably of what you want, though a standard container approach is *highly* advised.

Comment: Why are you allocating dynamic memory for a board in the display function?  You never `delete` the allocated memory.  Are you from C# or Java background?

Comment: When you use pointers to characters, the `cout` method expects a terminating nul character, '\0'.  Did you allocate enough space for this extra character?  Did you terminate the text with this extra character?

Comment: @Josh:  a *better* data structure would be `std::vector<std::string>`.  Each row would be a string.  This would be easier for the OP to print.